# Different results when running java awt code on Windows and Linux

Tags: java, windows, linux, awt

I have some code (unfortunately not written by me, or else I would know where to start looking for solutions) that draws some line graphs. When I run the code on my Windows machine and on the Linux machine, I get different results: on the Linux machine, the border around the legend is drawn with less height, resulting in some ugly problems when there are more than 3 items in the legend.

Is there some known difference when using

```
int getHeight(Graphics2D g, String text) {
    Rectangle2D bounds = g.getFont().getStringBounds(text, g.getFontMetrics().getFontRenderContext());
    return bounds.getHeight();
}
```

or where could the problem be?

Windows:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Linux:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.10) (6b20-1.9.10-0ubuntu1~10.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
```

UPDATE:

It was a rounding bug that seemingly only occurred with linux fonts, not with windows ones. Strange.

Comment: Are you using a different `LookAndFeel` on each platform?

Comment: I just create an image file, no special things are set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is based on `getFontMetrics()`, that return the font metric of the current font. I assume you're using default font in your program, and they are different in the different OS, so the result height might be different.

Comment: yeah, but the value should be correct, shouldn't it? If I draw a box around the font, it should work if I get the current height and add some padding around it and then draw it...

Comment: set as correct answer, because in windows, the returned values were whole integers, whereas in linux there was an additional double precision part that got lost because of a rounding bug.

Answer (score 1):

You are using different Java implementations and this kind of things are to be expected. I recommend that you uninstall the OpenJDK and install Oracle's Java in Linux.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that did not fix it. Still the same results with $ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)